# Equation of a simple harmonic motion (Finding the Amplitude and Phase Shift)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Question** : A weight is suspended from a spring and is vibrating vertically. Suppose the weight passes through its control position as it is **rising when t = 2.5**, then attains a **maximum upward displacement of 4** cm and passes through its central position as it is **descending when t = 3.5**. The motion is simple harmonic and described by equation of the form **f(t) = a sin (t - c)**. Where f(t) centimeters is the directed distance of the weight from its central position after t seconds and the positive direction is upward. Find this equation.

[Graph from the given values in the problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Y8s.jpg)

*My Analysis :*

- The amplitude (a) = 4, so the only missing value now is the "c" which tells us about the phase shift.
- The period formula is w = 2*pi / |b|; but the value of "c" nor the "b" is given hence I am stuck.
- The formula for phase shift is C / |b| but both are missing.

*From the book :*

The solution is w/2 = (7/5) - (5/2). So from that, w (the period) = 2.

The value of w was then substituted to the formula of the period to get "b".
w = 2*pi / |b|; b = 2*pi / 2 = pi.

The final answer is f(t) = a sin b(t-c) = **4 sin pi (t - 5/2)** where b = pi and c = 5/2.

*My questions :*

1. Where did the w/2 = 7/5 - 5/2 came from? What formula is that? The 7/5 and 5/2 is from t = 3.5 and 2.5 s but why is subtracted? Why is it equal to w/2? Where did the w/2 or period over 2 came from?
2. The calculated period is 2 while the "b" is pi. So when the values are substituted to the equation a sin b (t-c), why is c = 5/2?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you and God bless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where did the $\frac{w}{2} = \frac{7}{5} - \frac{5}{2}$ came from? What formula is that? The $\frac{7}{5}$ and $\frac{5}{2}$ is from $t = 3.5$ and $2.5$ s but why is subtracted? Why is it equal to $\frac{w}{2}$? Where did the $\frac{w}{2} or period over $2$ came from?

As I'm sure you know, the period is how long it takes for one cycle to occur, in a normal sinusoidal, $\sin(x)$, the period is just $2\pi$. In the problem (and the graph makes this more apparent), we're shown how far it takes to get through half of the period. That's why it's $\frac{w}{2}$. The two values for t are subtracted because we want to find the distance between the two points, A.K.A. how long half of the period is. (just like how the distance between $t=3$ and $t=5$ would be $2$)

2. The calculated period is $2$ while the "b" is pi. So when the values are substituted to the equation a sin b (t-c), why is $c = \frac{5}{2}$?

A great way to think of the phase shift for this is to ask yourself where it'll start. Again, this is much more obvious in the graph, but making the $c=\frac{5}{2}$ is just like saying "This is a sine function, but it starts at $\frac{5}{2}$ instead of $0$".

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: So in other words, period is from t1 to t2 and to find the "distance" from start to end (before the wave repeats), we will subtract t1 from t2? (Just like displacement = X2 - Xz). So period = t2 - t1 and since the wave is not complete (it is in half), period / 2 = t2 - t1. Right?

Comment: About the great way to think of phase shift. In the equation of sine function = A sin (Bx + C), let's say we have 4 sin (x + pi), so you're saying that it will start at pi? Does that apply in every function or equation? 

Also, thank you for the response. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right about the displacement. On phase shift, that's generally how I think about any old translation on the graph (i.e. y=(x-2) is the line y=x, but it starts two units to the right). But especially with sinusoidal equations, you want to be careful with period, at least in understanding what's going on. All that entails is making sure that the coefficient on the x variable is only 1. If that coefficient is something other than 1, then b was multiplied out into x and c. Other than that, yes, you've got it.